# Regex for filtering certain URL with multiple Keywords

Tags: java, regex

What I want to do is simple. I want to filter certain URL which contain specific keywords.

What I do at the moment is something like this:

```
http://.*Examplesite.com/.*(?!Keyword).*
```

Which works just fine for me. But when I want to filter for different Keywords and ignore in which sequence they are I would try this:

```
http://.*Examplesite.com/.*(?!Keyword1|?!Keyword2|...).*
```

This does not work for me. Also tried just using "?!" with Keyword1.
What is the correct way to solve this?
I just need the plain Regex example like the one I typed above.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use URL class, not regex

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: Yeah, probably you don't want to use a regex to parse URLs. However, let's say you want to. `(?!` is a negative look-ahead… it goes only in the beginning of the block, not after each `|`. Could you give me an example of a URL and what you expect out of it?

Comment: I checked those on online regex tester and they work

Comment: Why not using [`String#contains(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this tool whenever I need to do something with regex [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

It is unclear what you mean by filter the requests.  Do you want to drop the requests by simply matching the pattern or do you want to capture the values from the matches themselves?  This will change the complexity of the regex a lot.

I do caution that your final line seems to suggest you want a more complex expression.  While still regular this begins to include more complex features like look back to contextualize the match, and really ventures off the 'simple' path.

Since I can't comment yet, I'll update this answer to include a solution when answered.

EDIT: I don't think regex is the solution you are looking for especially if this list can get large.. however I think this could be a good start to what you're looking for.

```
    (?i)((?!dogs)(?!cats)[\.|/|\:|\w])+
```

This should only match strings which case insensitively don't contain dogs or cats.  I highly suggest you use the path from a URL, as this will also isolate this from any query parameter false positives as well as domain false positives.

To add more terms, or build this dynamically, just add more (?!word) blocks.  The rest of the expression matches a normal URI character set, but if you have anything else you need in there to allow, simply add another bar '|' and include the character you need to support.

If you want to get much smarter with it, I would suggest you probably look at another solution, as this is nearing the limit of utility for regular expressions.

Comment: For Example I have 3 URLs like this:

Comment: For Example I have 3 URLs like this: www.exampleone.com/videos/funny/cats
www.exampletwo.com/videos/sad/funeral
www.examplethree.com/videos/funstuff/dogs

I want to drop all URLs which contain either "dogs" or "cats".
With a regex which follows the example above I want to drop those two URL which contain the keywords.

Comment: Does the domain portion of the URL string hold any significance for you?  If not, you could simply work with the servlet path which would reduce the complexity a bunch.  Are you still including the requirement to hold the context significant? E.g. exclude dogs, unless its preceded by cats.  Meaning http://www.examplefour.com/videos/funny/cats/fight/dogs would not be dropped.

Comment: The domain is important since I do have different domains and need to filter them all in a different way. Also I need to avoid that something like examplefour.com/videos/funny/cats/fight/dogs would not be dropped. It should drop them without checking the order they are in.

Comment: You can also use * quantifier at the end of the regex if you would like to be able to match the empty string, but it really is up to you regarding how you're going to use this.

Comment: Did this satisfy your requirements?

The only remaining questions were things like https://www.example.com/videos/funny/avideo.html (with example.com being something like dogsexample.com) and https://www.example.com/videos/funny/avideo.html?param=dogs.

That is why I suggested instantiating a URL and then using the path to remove the extraneous text.  If this didn't satisfy the requirements, could you respond with more information?  If it did, could you mark the answer as accepted?